# Pausing ffmpeg stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

I'm running a client that reads video from a remote web cam:

```
ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Sometimes the web cam stops and after a while it get back on. I need to be able to resume the stream even if the web cam was off for few minutes. Someone already asked that [question](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-September/033528.html) on ffmpeg mailing list but didn't get any answer.